# SWF file:Can we use Adobe cs5 to develop SWF(Swif) files for mobile devices(Android , iphone)

Tags: iphone, android, flash-cs5

Can we use Adobe cs5 to develop SWF(Swif) files for mobile devices(Android , iphone). If possible please suggest me some tutorials. I am trying to search in internet but I am unable to get results.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not on the iPhone, since it doesn't support Flash.

Comment: Thanks, can u suggest me some tutorials for android